# getting the error as value error , what should i do if i get this error

Tags: python, softmax, collaboration

F.softmax(Model(input_ids, attention_mask), dim=1)
and the error is
Found unexpected instance while processing input tensors for keras functional model. Expecting KerasTensor which is from tf.keras.Input() or output from keras layer call(). Got: tensor([[  101,  1192,  1169,  ...,     0,     0,     0],
[  101,   146,  3983,  ...,     0,     0,     0],
[  101,   122,   119,  ..., 17424, 28404,   102],
...,
[  101,  2543,  3014,  ...,     0,     0,     0],
[  101,  1960,  1614,  ...,     0,     0,     0],
[  101,   138,  8661,  ...,     0,     0,     0]])

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're mixing PyTorch and TensorFlow syntax in your code. F.softmax() is from the PyTorch library, while the error message you're getting suggests that you're trying to use a Keras (TensorFlow) model.

If you're using TensorFlow/Keras:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers

model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')) 
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

Comment: and the error was : name 'keras' is not defined